# Dynamic update statement without looping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to following table to update the column_name for specific date:

Table: testg

```
create table testg
(
column_date datetime,
column_name varchar(100)
);
```

Records insertion:

```
insert into testg values('2005-01-01','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-02','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-03','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-04','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-05','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-06','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-07','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-01','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-01','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-08','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-09','');
insert into testg values('2005-01-10','');
```

**Note**: Now I want to update name for between two dates without using loop. The dates are passing as a parameter to update and names too.

```
Declare @dates varchar(max) = '2005-01-01to2005-01-03,2005-01-04to2005-01-05,2005-01-06to2005-01-08'
Declare @names varchar(max) = 'D1,D2,D3'
```

It has to update the name `D1,D2,D3` to the dates

**Expected Outcomes will be**:

```
    column_date             column_name 
-----------------------------------------       
2005-01-01 00:00:00.000         D1
2005-01-02 00:00:00.000         D1
2005-01-03 00:00:00.000         D1
2005-01-04 00:00:00.000         D2
2005-01-05 00:00:00.000         D2
2005-01-06 00:00:00.000         D3
2005-01-07 00:00:00.000         D3
2005-01-01 00:00:00.000         D1
2005-01-01 00:00:00.000         D1
2005-01-08 00:00:00.000         D3
2005-01-09 00:00:00.000 
2005-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**CASE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to achieve this:

```
UPDATE  testg
SET     column_name = CASE WHEN column_date BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-01-03'
                           THEN 'D1'
                           WHEN column_date BETWEEN '2005-01-04' AND '2005-01-05'
                           THEN 'D2'
                           WHEN column_date BETWEEN '2005-01-06' AND '2005-01-08'
                           THEN 'D3'
                           ELSE ''
                      END
```

<kbd>[Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b114/2)</kbd>

Comment: Yes this is right! But how do I prepare dynamic case statement. Because values are  dynamic, it may 3 or 30 also in the given variables.

Comment: @MAK I'd change the input so that it's in a better format, as your method of passing in those values is terrible. Consider constructing a reference table (or xml) instead with: date from, date to and update value columns. Then you can perform an update without dynamic sql. It's difficult to advise further as you've not specified how the variables are setup, be it sql or some external code.

Comment: @MAK: SQL Server 2008 and later versions have [UDTT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526.aspx "User-Defined Table Types"), you could use one to pass your data.

Answer (score 1):

You could also represent the input in the form of a table and use it like this:

```
UPDATE testg
SET column_name = ISNULL(
  (
    SELECT
      s
    FROM
      (VALUES
        ('2005-01-01', '2005-01-03', 'D1'),
        ('2005-01-01', '2005-01-03', 'D2'),
        ('2005-01-01', '2005-01-03', 'D3')
      ) AS v (d1, d2, s)
    WHERE
      testg.column_date BETWEEN v.d1 AND v.d2
  ),
  ''
);
```

or like this:

```
UPDATE
  t
SET
  column_name = ISNULL(v.s, '')
FROM
  testg AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    (VALUES
      ('2005-01-01', '2005-01-03', 'D1'),
      ('2005-01-01', '2005-01-03', 'D2'),
      ('2005-01-01', '2005-01-03', 'D3')
    ) AS v (d1, d2, s)
    ON t.column_date BETWEEN v.d1 AND v.d2
;
```

As an aside, please note that the `YYYY-MM-DD` format is not unambiguous when the target is a `datetime`, meaning the value's interpretation depends on the SET LANGUAGE/SET DATEFORMAT settings. If in this case you are working with dates only, consider either using the `YYYYMMDD` format or switching to the `date` type (`YYYY-MM-DD` is unambiguous for `date`).